# Webpack : split and share vendor chunk across pages not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I configured Webpack to split vendor and app chunk. vendor chunk are used across all page.
the vendor file work only for the app file that built it. The project has multiple page, each page built on it own and have its own app.js and bse.js. I want to use bse.js across all pages.

```
page A have:
 - app.js
 - bse.js
page B have:
 - app.js
 - bse.js
page C have:
 - app.js
 - bse.js
```

I want to use bse.js shared vendor chunk for all pages. So browsers would load the file only one time.

Here is my configuration file for each page.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');


var entry = {
    app:path.join(__dirname, './jvs/app.js') ,
    bse:['react', 'react-dom']  //Vendor bundle
};

var commonPlugin = [new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: "bse",
    filename:"bse.js",
    minChunks: Infinity
})];
var commonPluginProduction = [new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: "bse",
    filename:"bse.js",
    minChunks: Infinity
})];

// We need to uglify that code on deploy
var uglifyPlugin = [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(
            {
                compress: {
                    drop_console: true
                },
                output: {
                    comments: false
                }
            }
        ),
    ];


// The loader transforms our JSX content
var module = {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /.js?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['react','es2015','stage-0','stage-1','stage-2','stage-3'],

            }
        }
    ]
}; 

grunt.initConfig({
    webpack: {

        dev: {
            entry: entry,
            plugins: commonPlugin,
            watch: true,

            keepalive: true,
            stats: {
                timings: true
            },


            devtool: "#inline-source-map", // Here we get our sourcemap
            output: {
                filename: 'app.js',
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out')
            },


            module: module
        },
        dist: {
            entry: entry,
            plugins: commonPluginProduction.concat(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                    "process.env": {
                        // This has effect on the react lib size
                        "NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production")
                    }
                }),
                //new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
                uglifyPlugin),
            output: {
                filename: 'app.min.js',
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out')
            },
            module: module
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-collection');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['webpack:dev']);
grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['webpack:dist']);
```

}

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: I have separated build for Page A, Page B, page C.  Page A built output with app.js and bse.js, Page A work fine own it own bse.js(vendor) and app.js. But for other Page,B,C use shared bse.js (vendor)  from Page A not working. It should work normally